# Using 'read_batch_record_features' with an Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

(I'm using tensorflow 1.0 and Python 2.7)

I'm having trouble getting an Estimator to work with queues. Indeed, if I use the deprecated SKCompat interface with custom data files and a given batch size, the model trains properly. I'm trying to use the new interface with an input_fn that batches features out of TFRecord files (equivalent to my custom data files). The scripts runs properly but the loss value doesn't change after 200 or 300 steps. It seems that the model is looping on a small input batch (this would explain why the loss converges so fast).

I have a 'run.py' script that looks like the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import learn, metrics

#[...]
evalMetrics = {'accuracy':learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn=metrics.streaming_accuracy)}
runConfig = learn.RunConfig(save_summary_steps=10)
estimator = learn.Estimator(model_fn=myModel,
                            params=myParams,
                            modelDir='/tmp/myDir',
                            config=runConfig)

session = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph())

with session.as_default():
  tf.global_variables_initializer()
  coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=session,coord=coordinator)

  estimator.fit(input_fn=lambda: inputToModel(trainingFileList),steps=10000)

  estimator.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: inputToModel(evalFileList),steps=10000,metrics=evalMetrics)

  coordinator.request_stop()
  coordinator.join(threads)
session.close()
```

My inputToModel function looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def inputToModel(fileList):
  features = {'rawData': tf.FixedLenFeature([100],tf.float32),
              'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64)}
  tensorDict = tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_record_features(fileList,
                                batch_size=100,
                                features=features,
                                randomize_input=True,
                                reader_num_threads=4,
                                num_epochs=1,
                                name='inputPipeline')
  tf.local_variables_initializer()
  data = tensorDict['rawData']
  labelTensor = tensorDict['label']
  inputTensor = tf.reshape(data,[-1,10,10,1])

  return inputTensor,labelTensor
```

Any help or suggestions is welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: `tf.global_variables_initializer().run()`

I wanna do a similar thing but I do not know how to use Estimator API with multi-threading. There is an Experiment class for serving too - might be useful

**delete** line `session = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph())`
and `session.close()` and try:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
```

Comment: It doesn't work: I get an error saying: "ValueError: Cannot use the given session to execute operation: the operation's graph is different from the session's graph."

Comment: I updated answer for you with the new idea. The exceptions might be due to double session initialization... I can not test your code.

Comment: OK. I don't get the exceptions anymore but it does not solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: other suggestion I can give you is to use Experiment class, not Estimator. please find the details here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment?hl=bn

Comment: I post similar more generic question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529598/estimator-with-coordinator-as-an-input-function-for-reading-input-data-in-distri

Comment: I have tried using the Experiment class and the 'train_and_evaluate' method. I now get 1 step for training and then the evaluation starts. Still no proper training.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: By setting min_eval_frequency to 0 in the train_and_evaluate method, it avoids launching the evaluation after the first step. But it still doesn't solve my training problem.