# Estimator with Coordinator as an input function for reading input data in distributed fashion in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

The CNN cifar10 tutorial (tensor flow tutorials) gives an example of low-level API use for reading data as an independent job to train model (with multiple GPU).
Is it possible to use high-level API Estimator with low-level threading support and multi/single GPUs training?

I am looking for a way to combine both:

- The custom Estimator from high-level API, details https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators
- input_fn as a queue, which gives the same functionality which is described in https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data for Coordinator class

  ```
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
  ```

It is not straightforward to me!

Comment: There is a related question at stack overflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506384/using-read-batch-record-features-with-an-estimator/42508760#42508760

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I push a code to [here](https://github.com/BobLiu20/Classification_Nets/blob/master/tensorflow/training/train_estimator.py).
It is support input_fn as a queue when using estimator. High-level API Estimator with low-level threading support and multi/single GPUs training. And easy to customer code all of you need.

Comment: BTW, I am using tensorflow 1.3.0